# What is the best way in PHP to append one multidimensional array to another?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to glue a couple of indexed arrays containing `n` associative arrays each (example below). I don't care about the indexes of the outer array, I care only for the keys from inner arrays. I've tried a couple of methods and (surprisingly) only one of them - the most ugly - actually works. So I began to wonder if there's something clever/fast that I'm missing.

PHP version: 5.3+ (if that matters)

**This is what I have:**

```
$arrayA = array(
        array(
            'foo' => 1,
            'bar' => 2,
            'baz' => 3
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => 12,
            'bar' => 22,
            'baz' => 32
        ),
    );

    $arrayB = array(
        array(
            'foo' => 21,
            'bar' => 22,
            'baz' => 23
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => 212,
            'bar' => 222,
            'baz' => 232
        ),
    );
```

**This is what I want to have:**

```
    $arrayC = array(
        array(
            'foo' => 1,
            'bar' => 2,
            'baz' => 3
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => 12,
            'bar' => 22,
            'baz' => 32
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => 21,
            'bar' => 22,
            'baz' => 23
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => 212,
            'bar' => 222,
            'baz' => 232
        ),
    );
```

**This is what I've tried:**

```
    $arrayD = $arrayA;
    foreach($arrayB as $value)
    {
        $arrayD[] = $value;
    }

    $arrayE = array_push($arrayA, $arrayB);
    $arrayF = $arrayA + $arrayB;
    $arrayG = array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB);

    print_r($arrayC == $arrayD); //TRUE - it works
    print_r($arrayC == $arrayE); //FALSE
    print_r($arrayC == $arrayF); //FALSE
    print_r($arrayC == $arrayG); //FALSE
```

**Why I've thought that `array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB)` don't work:**

```
    $arrayD = $arrayA;
    foreach($arrayB as $value)
    {
        $arrayD[] = $value;
    }

    $arrayE = array_push($arrayA, $arrayB); // <-- after this line $arrayA is already broken
    $arrayF = $arrayA + $arrayB;
    $arrayG = array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB); // because $arrayA was broken I thought it didn't work
```

Is there any simpler/faster/more clever way than the foreach() approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php) is what you're looking for:

```
 $arrayC = array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB);
```

See working example here: http://codepad.org/IJ8UM6Uz

Comment: Are you sure? I've added a codepad link where everything works fine. ;)

Comment: You should check this page before doing array comparison : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @FriederikeS of course it works (unless of course you're a moron who calls array_push($arrayA, $arrayB) first.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure that [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) should work well. Maybe they don't equate exactly the same but they should be virtually identical. It might be a semantic that's blocking it out from returning true, why not print them side by side and figure out the difference?

Also possibly [this method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php#51121) instead.

Comment: array_merge() doesn't work and the second method seems much more complicated then foreach()

Comment: @MythThrazz: In case it is you, I do not think it is necessary to down-vote every answer that does not work. Folks are just trying to help..

Comment: I'd say the same thing. The array_merge() function does exactly what you want. `Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.`

Comment: @Raidenace true especially when I'm wrong.

Of course I was wrong and array_merge() works (it didn't work because I broke the testcase).

Comment: @MythThrazz: Its all good bro. We all get carried away at times :)

Comment: @henasraf Please edit the answer so I can take back that idiotic downvote of mine.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the OP says that `array_merge` does not work:

```
<?
$arrayA = array(
        array(
            'foo' => 1,
            'bar' => 2,
            'baz' => 3
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => 12,
            'bar' => 22,
            'baz' => 32
        ),
    );

    $arrayB = array(
        array(
            'foo' => 21,
            'bar' => 22,
            'baz' => 23
        ),
        array(
            'foo' => 212,
            'bar' => 222,
            'baz' => 232
        ),
    );

//using ARRAY_MERGE
echo "<pre>";
$arrayC = array_merge($arrayA,$arrayB);
echo "ArrayC<br>";
print_r($arrayC); 

//using OP's method
$arrayD = $arrayA;
    foreach($arrayB as $value)
    {
        $arrayD[] = $value;
    }
echo "ArrayD<br>";
print_r($arrayD); 
?>
```

Results:

```
ArrayC //array_merge
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 1
            [bar] => 2
            [baz] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 12
            [bar] => 22
            [baz] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 21
            [bar] => 22
            [baz] => 23
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 212
            [bar] => 222
            [baz] => 232
        )

)

ArrayD //OP's method..
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 1
            [bar] => 2
            [baz] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 12
            [bar] => 22
            [baz] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 21
            [bar] => 22
            [baz] => 23
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 212
            [bar] => 222
            [baz] => 232
        )

)
```

I would like to know the difference...